# Mac OS X Profile Manager

Tags: mac, mac-osx-server, configuration-management

I am wondering if when I set settings in profile manager if they should take place immediately. They currently only take effect after a restart or log out/in. I expected to send a push notification of some sort and have the settings take place immediately. If choose lock device - the device does lock immediately - so that part is working. Was just curious about if the settings should be immediate too and what I can do to troubleshoot. Before anyone suggests the firewall - firewall is off on the server and devices. Everything is on the same subnet so there is no routing taking place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New profiles should be installed on the device quickly. If there are no network issues, my experience is that it should take under a minute for the device to get the update. Note that even with the server & devices on the same network, there can still be delays/problems due to internet connectivity: to push an update, the server sends a notification to one of Apple's push notification server (over the internet), that forwards the notification to the device (again, over the internet and subject to firewall etc issues), and then finally the device makes an HTTP (/HTTPS) connection to the server to actually fetch the new profile.

But that doesn't necessarily mean the profile will take effect quickly. I've seen inconsistent behavior with programs/system components not loading the new settings until they're restarted (e.g. by a logout or reboot). You can check whether the new profile has been downloaded in System Preferences -> Profiles pane, or with the `profiles` command; if it shows up there, the download worked but the relevant program hasn't noticed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

In OS X it depends on the setting. Some settings require certain services to restart.

A great example of this is the Dock. When you send a setting to add an item to the dock the user usually has to logout and then log back in because it requires the dock to refresh.